# How do I convert long doubles to char arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am running a C++ program to sort strings as numbers.

I am saving strings in a char array vector but want to sort numbers as numbers so I am converting number strings into long doubles by calling "tonum()" then converting them back to strings when I am done by calling "tostring()". I am calling "numstr()" strictly for readability and debugging. I convert numbers 0 through 7 and the 6th number across for each value changes every time I run it. In my actual program, the first 5 numbers also seem to change. How do I get consistent results for a long double so that I can properly sort long doubles in char arrays?

```
#include<iostream>
std::string::size_type sz;
//___________________________________________________
std::string tonum(std::string str)
{
   const int len = sizeof(long double);
   std::string out = "0000000000000000";
   union
   {
      long double dbl;
      char array[len];
   };
   try
   {
      dbl = stold(str);
   }
   catch(std::exception &err)
   {
      dbl = 0;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      std::cout << (int)array[i] << "\n";
      out[len-i-1] = array[i];
   }
   return(out);
}
//___________________________________________________
std::string fromnum(std::string str)
{
   const int len = sizeof(long double);
   std::string out = "";
   union
   {
      long double dbl;
      char array[len];
   };
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
      array[len-i-1] = str[i];
   }
   out = std::to_string(dbl);
   return(out);
}

//_____________________________________________________
std::string numstr(std::string str)
{
   std::string out = fromnum(str) + ":";
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
      std::string look = std::to_string(str[i]);
      int lookint = stold(look,&sz);
      if (lookint < 0) lookint += 256;
      std::string look2 = std::to_string(lookint);
      out += look2 + " ";
   }
   return(out);
}
//_____________________________________________________
int main()
{
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("0")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("1")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("2")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("3")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("4")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("5")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("6")) << "\n";
   std::cout << numstr(tonum("7")) << "\n";
}
//_____________________________________________________
```

Comment: *"I am converting number strings into long doubles by calling `tonum()`"* That's not what the current implementation of the function does. The function parses a string to a `long double` and then relies on undefined behaviour; at best it copies the byte representation from the `long double` to the backing array of a string. But what happens, if one of the bytes is `0`?

Comment: My understanding is that the c++ string itself can have 0s. It is other functions that terminate at 0. I just figured out that it is the array itself in the union in "tonum" that keeps changing. How can this be?

Comment: I also determined that the string needs to be 16 characters because a long double using 10 bytes but is 16 bytes long

Comment: Why not just return long double? Why all the shenanigans with a char buffer then that is pushed into a string? `array[len-i-1]` why from the back? And why then don't you use `std::vector<char>` or `std::array<char, sizeof(long double)>`, why the union and then array and then string? `so that I can properly sort long doubles in char arrays?` "long doubles" in "char arrays"? Is this related to the question? Are you asking XY question?

Comment: `std::string look = std::to_string(str[i]);` What is going on from this point? Why are you converting a `char` to a string and then trying to convert a char to long double, and then convert it to an int, and then when that int is less then zero, adding 256 to it and converting back to a string? Are you trying to do `std::cout << (int)str[i]` like you did above? `7 and the 6th number across for each value changes every time` You program outputs _a lot_ of numbers. Which of the output numbers changes? What compiler, compiler options, architecture and system are you using?

Comment: I am converting long doubles to char arrays because it is a char array database that stores  variable length strings as well.

Comment: I fixed the problem but am not quite sure why it fixed it. I assigned the call to 'tonum()' to a string instead of calling it directly and that kept the union from giving a faulty result.

Comment: I also realized I needed to zero out the entire 16 byte long double before assigning it to long double.